# How to use SSRS Reports in PHP Zend Application?

Tags: php, sql-server, reporting-services

We have application in Zend PHP Framework and MSSQL As DB.
we need to use the **SSRS Reports** for reporting feature.

We have set up the Reporting Server , we have also with using the Report Designer uploded the rdp file and run it, it consumes user id and password and displayed reports.

1.what we want is how can we render the rdp reports to our application ?

[ANY BUDDY WHO HAVE USED SSRS WITH PHP ? ]

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: could you check if you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259178/uncaught-soapfault-exception-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments, I think there might be problem with your login credentials or the Service URL. Make sure you are using the WEB Service Url in your code and not the virtual directory path.